# How do you initialize type alias?

Tags: elm

How do you initialize type alias in Elm?

Model is below.

```
type alias Model =
    { name : String
    , tags : List Tag
    , token : Token
    , jwt : String 
    }
```

Token is below.

```
type alias Token =
    { accessToken : String
    }
```

I am try to initialize like below.

```
init : String -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init flags =
    ( Model "" [] "" "", Cmd.none )
```

But, an error occurs like

```
The 3rd argument to `Model` is not what I expect:

55|     ( Model "" [] "" "", Cmd.none )
                      ^^
This argument is a string of type:

    String

But `Model` needs the 3rd argument to be:

    Token
```

I know 3rd argument is not string.
But, I just don't know how to initialize custom type in init function.

Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: `Model "" [] (Token "") ""` doesn't work?

Comment: Wow it worked and completely makes sense!
Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 5):

You have two options for initializing a type alias.  The first, like in your use with `Model`, is to treat the alias name like a constructor function.  To do this inline, you'll need to wrap it in parenthesis:

```
Model "" [] (Token "") ""
```

You could also take this approach but initialize it in a separate line:

```
let
    initialToken =
        Token ""
in
Model "" [] initialToken ""
```

If it's useful to have an `initialToken` that's available in general (like it's useful to have an `init` version of your `Model`), you may want that to be a top-level declaration that your export from the module, rather than having it hidden in a `let`. Or it may make sense for `Token` to be its own module with its own `init` that gets exposed.

The second option is to just construct the type directly without the alias.  In this case, that would mean creating a record with an `accessToken` field:

```
Model "" [] { accessToken = "" } ""
```

Comment: How would you instantiate a `type alias Example = {}`? I understand that this should be a type in this example. But for creating a skeleton of the program it might be useful. I thought `Example ()` might work but doesn't seem to.

Comment: You can just refer to that type by `Example` (or `{}`).  Since there are no fields in the record, there are no arguments to the `Example` constructor.  See https://ellie-app.com/7bB322pk5HBa1

Comment: Yeah thanks, I realize it was a pretty stupid comment now. However I initially thought that you always had to pass a value to the constructor. Cheers!